# what is the mistake in printing prime numbers between two numbers?

Tags: c++

i tried writing code in c++ for printing prime no.s between 2 numbers . But the output is not satisfactory as it prints the no. 2 - 3 times and also shows non prime numbers.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int n;

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cout << "enter the first no." << endl;
    cin >> a;

    cout << "Enter the second no." << endl;
    cin >> b;

    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
    {
        for (int n = 2; n < i; n++)
        {
            if (i % n == 0)
            {
                break; 
            }
    
            cout << n << endl;  
        }   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

i was expecting the prime no. but it is not coming.

Comment: Please refrain from tag spamming. This question has nothing to do with either Python or C. And your print statement is in the wrong place.

Comment: Stop screaming in the title.

Comment: @WeijunZhou editted

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) & [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

You have declared n outside the scope, but within the second for loop you have redeclared it again (int n = ...). This n and the n outside the main function are different. Also, while checking whether your number is prime, you are printing n which is why you are getting multiple numbers (those numbers correspond to the value of n in a particular iteration). Use a flag (a boolean perhaps) to check if a number is prime or not, and then check outside the second loop and print accordingly. The corrected code is given below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int n;
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cout<<"enter the first no."<<endl;
    cin>>a;

    cout<<"Enter the second no."<<endl;
    cin>>b;

    for (int i = a; i <=b; i++)
    {
        bool isprime = true;
        for (n = 2; n < i; n++) /* notice no int n = 2 */
        {
            if (i%n==0)
            {
                isprime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isprime && i != 1)
            cout << n << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Fixed a bug pointed out by tbxfreeware.

Comment: Extracting code into a function `bool isPrime(int n)` would even be better.

Comment: @Jarod42 True but OP looks new to programming so I tried to keep logic and code hand in hand.

Comment: Just a heads-up: this program gives strange (incorrect) results when 1 is tested. The easiest way to see this is to run the program, and enter 1 as both the "first" and "second" no..

Comment: Separate concern with functions makes the code simpler to understand (for both beginners and more advanced programmers).

Answer (score 1):

###### In general, global variables are problematic

As was noted in the comments, variable `n` is declared twice in your program, first as a global variable, and then later, as a local variable. After its declaration, global `n` is never referenced again. All computation and output comes from local `n`.

You can prove this by simply deleting the global declaration. In general, global variables are problematic in large projects, anyway, so getting rid of global `n` is probably a good idea.

While I'm at it, I am going to get rid of `using namespace std`. Professionals rarely use it. Instead, they type out `std::` every time they reference a name from the Standard Library.

With those changes, your program becomes:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    std::cout << "enter the first no." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a;

    std::cout << "Enter the second no." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> b;

    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
    {
        for (int n = 2; n < i; n++)
        {
            if (i % n == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            std::cout << n << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I ran it, attempting to find prime numbers between 1 and 10.

Here is the output:

```
enter the first no.
1
Enter the second no.
10
2
2
3
4
2
3
4
5
6
2
```

To help make sense of the output, I added the following output statement at the top of the outer loop.

```cpp
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Checking i: Is " << i << " prime?\n";
        for (int n = 2; n < i; n++)
        {
            //...
```

This give me some more clues about what is going wrong:

```
enter the first no.
1
Enter the second no.
10
Checking i: Is 1 prime?
Checking i: Is 2 prime?
Checking i: Is 3 prime?
2
Checking i: Is 4 prime?
Checking i: Is 5 prime?
2
3
4
Checking i: Is 6 prime?
Checking i: Is 7 prime?
2
3
4
5
6
Checking i: Is 8 prime?
Checking i: Is 9 prime?
2
Checking i: Is 10 prime?
```

This is too much output. When checking 7, for instance, the only output should be 7 itself. Instead, the output is a *list of all the values checked in the inner `n` loop.* Ditto for 3 and 5.

Evidently, the `std::cout` statement in the `n` loop should not be there. Why am I outputting `n` at all? Variable `i` is the one I care about. I want to know whether `i` is a prime number, not `n`.

This version outputs `i`, instead of `n`. It also moves the `std::cout` statement out of the `n`loop, placing it just below that loop.

```cpp
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Checking i: Is " << i << " prime?\n";
        for (int n = 2;; n < i; n++)
        {
            if (i % n == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
```

Now, I get this output:

```
enter the first no.
1
Enter the second no.
10
Checking i: Is 1 prime?
1
Checking i: Is 2 prime?
2
Checking i: Is 3 prime?
3
Checking i: Is 4 prime?
4
Checking i: Is 5 prime?
5
Checking i: Is 6 prime?
6
Checking i: Is 7 prime?
7
Checking i: Is 8 prime?
8
Checking i: Is 9 prime?
9
Checking i: Is 10 prime?
10
```

That does not seem like much progress! Now, everything is prime. The good news is that the right number is being output. When testing 7, for instance, 7 is what gets printed.

###### Single responsiblity

At this point, I want to isolate the test for prime numbers in a separate function. As things stand, function main is doing three things:

1. Input and output
2. Run a "driver" loop which selects which numbers to check
3. Test whether a given number is prime

When things go wrong, it is hard to debug, because the three activities are all mixed together.

A good general principle is to limit each function to a single responsibility. In this case, I want to create a function `is_prime` that returns a `bool`. To start things out, I will just return `true` for every number:

```cpp
bool is_prime(int const n)
{
    return true;
}
```

This greatly simplifies function `main`.

```cpp
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Checking i: Is " << i << " prime?\n";
        if (is_prime(i))
        {
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Because the *stub function* `is_prime` returns `true` for every number, the output is exactly the same as it was before. Everything is prime.

Fortunately, that is easy to fix. The trick is to return `false` the first time `n % j` is zero. If you make it all the way to the end of the loop without returning `false`, then `n` must be prime. In that case, return `true`.

I also put a special case right at the top: Anything less than 2 is not prime, so return `false`.

```cpp
bool is_prime(int const n)
{
    if (n < 2)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int j = 2; j < n; ++j)
    {
        if (n % j == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

###### The complete program

For clarity, here is the finished program, all in one place. I have removed the extra output statment I inserted earlier, at the top of the `i` loop. Instead, I print a simple header.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

bool is_prime(int const n)
{
    if (n < 2)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int j = 2; j < n; ++j)
    {
        if (n % j == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    std::cout << "enter the first no." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a;

    std::cout << "Enter the second no." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> b;

    std::cout << "\nPrime numbers between " 
        << a << " and " << b << ":\n";
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
    {
        if (is_prime(i))
        {
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output it generates:

```
enter the first no.
1
Enter the second no.
10

Prime numbers between 1 and 10:
2
3
5
7
```